Magento 2.4.6 security issues? Credit card fields added into checkout / payment module
We have a magento 2.4.6 and we are using the PAYPLUG payment module during checkout.
It is configured so none datas about credit cards are asked on our own website BUT a popup opens leading customer to payplug website, where the payment actually occurs.
Today i noticed that 'credit cxard' input fields are added to the payment choice, below credit card module of payplug.
Those fields are not part of payplug module.
But i can't find which fiel or code was modified. I don't find anything specific...
Below my printscreen, everything in blue should not be there:

and when i check the code, i can find this:

Any idea? I already checked app/code or /vendor for the code found, but can't find anything specific...

It seems like somebody injected a payment skimmer into your site. Check cms_block for suspect JavaScript and make sure to invalidate your old crypt key.
Better yet, run a malware scanner such as ecomscan.
More info on this attack: https://sansec.io/research/cosmicsting

Hi, i checked last modified cms block and could not find anything. I also looked for "%js%" and "%java%" into table of cms block in phpmyadmin and found nothing.
I am now starting ecomscan. Will let you know.

Well, ecmscan found something but even if they claim there is a free trial... The results are hidden...

i found the trouble.
usually a specific code is added and when you are used to this, you can recognize it.
In this case, one of the several footer was modified to add a call to an external url.
And it was that url that contains the code of the javascript. So nearly nothing was present on my own server/website.

We recently faced the same problem. It started with random cms blocks added to the website and then scripts were injected to the blocks. The scripts started with function _randomcharacters. Althought we removed the scripts, they kept adding to the blocks until one day, we saw the same card details inputs on checkout.
We rotated the encryption keys but it didn't stop the injection.
As a temporary fix, we have banned ips from some suspicious countries and added
if (preg_match('/\/rest\/.*\/cmsBlock/m', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    http_response_code(503);
    echo "Service Unavailable";
    exit();
}

at the beginning of app/bootstrap.php
Next step is to apply the security patch and rotate the encryption keys again.
I hope this will help someone.

Based on the screenshot you provided, the fields seem to be from Authorize.net, as indicated by the ID "authorize_cc_number."
Regarding the redirect issue you're facing, it appears to be related to the Payplug settings. Please refer to the installation and module tabs, where you can find the proper setup instructions.

Hello, the payplug module was working perfectly since ages, and the setup is right.
That fields have been added somewhere but i can't find where.

These fields are related to Authorize.net, so please check if that module is enabled, visible, or possibly overridden.

php bin/magento module:status
gives no trace of an authorize.net module.
